# Reading error status code in R and handling the exception

Tags: r, http

I am getting some data from a server in json or xml format , and the server is sending status code in header like 500,200,404 etc. So how can I get the error status code or the error and handle it in R. If I can get a simple sample code or any reference, it would work.

Or if there is some other way around that will also work.

Comment: you can parse the response from your http requests and collect the status value. You need to give us a minimum reproducible example to work with though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking to collect the status responses, you just need to inspect/parse what you get back.

```
library(httr)

GET("www.google.com")$status

# [1] 200
```

As a starting point for error handling... if you just want console warnings then you can use the function of the same name.

```
info_get <- GET("www.google.com")

if (info_get$status == 200) {

  warning(paste0("Response ", info_get$status, " received from target."))

}

# Warning message:
# Response 200 received from target.
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have one more question that, now I want to throw this http status code if it is not 200 so that it will can be handled by someone who is consuming the service how will I do that? Like I want to throw the http standard error code or success code.